# Stop/Cancel running threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

In my windows service application, I started multiple threads as:

```
class ConsumingEnumerableDemo
{
   // Demonstrates: 
   //      BlockingCollection<T>.Add() 
   //      BlockingCollection<T>.CompleteAdding() 
   //      BlockingCollection<T>.GetConsumingEnumerable() 
   public static void BC_GetConsumingEnumerable()
   {
       using (BlockingCollection<int> bc = new BlockingCollection<int>())
       {

           // Kick off a producer task
           Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
           {
               for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
               {
                   bc.Add(i);
                   Thread.Sleep(100); // sleep 100 ms between adds
               }

               // Need to do this to keep foreach below from hanging
               bc.CompleteAdding();
           });

           // Now consume the blocking collection with foreach. 
           // Use bc.GetConsumingEnumerable() instead of just bc because the 
           // former will block waiting for completion and the latter will 
           // simply take a snapshot of the current state of the underlying collection. 
           foreach (var item in bc.GetConsumingEnumerable())
           {
               Console.WriteLine(item);
           }
        }
      }
    }
```

If I want to stop the tasks, how?
I heard about "Cancellation Tokens" but not sure how to apply it to the case.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/3689765/438180

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define a [Cancellation Token Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

And use it like this:

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                bc.Add(i);
                Thread.Sleep(100); // sleep 100 ms between adds
                cts.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }

            // Need to do this to keep foreach below from hanging
            bc.CompleteAdding();
        },cts.Token);
```

When you want to cancel your task, use:

```
cts.Cancel();
```

Also you might want take a look at these blog posts:

1. [Parallel Programming: Task Cancellation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/07/19/parallel-programming-task-cancellation.aspx)
2. [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx)

Comment: If you do this, you'll either have to put the `CompleteAdding` in a `finally` block, or call `CompleteAdding` from somewhere else. Otherwise the consumer will block indefinitely.